# Data for energy drink purchases in Germany and Austria

Tags: data-request, food

I am looking for statistics on sales of energy drinks in Germany and Austria; 
percentages, rankings of purchases of different drinks like Red Bull.

Comment: What kind of statistics you are looking for?

Comment: Percentages, rankings of purchases of different drinks like Red Bull etc.

Comment: AFAIK, some libraries provide access to [Euromonitor](http://www.euromonitor.com/energy-drinks-in-germany/report).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any free and open, recent dataset for such retail data. You probably have to purchase an appropriate dataset from a commercial data provider, e.g. [GfK](http://www.gfk.com/de/) (I don't know if they indeed sell this particular dataset).

As a workaround you could use [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/) data as a proxy for sales data, making some generous assumptions of course

In R, you could do this to fetch data from their API:

```
library(gtrendsR)
library(ggplot2)

energy_drinks_trend <- gtrends(c("red bull", "Bier", "Coca Cola"),  geo = c("DE"), hl="DE")
energy_drinks_trend <- energy_drinks_trend$interest_over_time
ggplot(energy_drinks_trend, aes(date, hits, color=keyword)) +
        geom_line() +
        ylab("Hits/Day") +
        xlab("Year") +
        ggtitle("Google trends: Energy Drinks Trend", subtitle = "Searches in Germany, last 5 years")
```

Result:

[image: energy drinks searches]

This Google Trends data might be questionable or misleading, but it is better than nothing.

You can see declining trends for overpriced sugary drinks, but an increasing trend for Beer (contrary to sales data published by German Breweries or alcohol tax data) , and some weird cyclicity + peaks.